# Can I ask this question about Cyber Weapons?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, question-quality

I was going through this recent Washington Post article on [Cyber Weapons](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/jan/28/air-forces-cyber-weapon-system-reaches-full-operat/). Can anyone please explain:

(1) What are the various Types of Cyber Weapons that are currently available?

(2) How are these Cyber Weapons evolving?In other words how are they being upgraded?

Answer (score 4):

This would not be a good question here, no.

Cyber weapon can describe anything in the information security attack space - so the list could be as long as you want (ie it fails our answerability test) and as to being upgraded, in some cases that would make no sense at all.